# What does 'Off' mean in the output of nvidia-smi?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia, tesla

I run a tensorflow code in the GPU.
The image bellow shows the nvidia-smi info::

I want ask what does 'Off' mean in the output of nvidia-smi?
Also what does the ""C"" type means here??

My code run in the GPU or CPU in this situation????

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"C" stands for compute. "G" stands for graphics. Both run on the graphics card. "Off" is in reference to "Persistence-M", which stands for Persistence Mode which keeps the [driver always loaded](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/823166/cuda-programming-and-performance/what-does-off-mean-in-the-output-of-nvidia-smi-/post/4500832/#4500832).